# getting error for using async: false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to store some data outside `ajax` call in a variable. So, I am using `async: false` option in `ajax`. But it gives me an error:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

See my code below:

```
var internal_tags = null;

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType:'json',
    contentType:'application/json',
    url: '/ajax-search-suggestions',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        asignVariable(data);
    }
});

// get internal tags
function asignVariable(data){
    internal_tags = data;
}
```

I need to save `ajax success` data into `internal_tags` variable. If I remove the option `async: false`, data are not saved in variable. So how I can remove the error or how to save `ajax success data` in the variable which is outside of ajax.

Comment: dont use async false

Comment: Not only you should be getting an error, but your keyboard should be taken away for even considering using `async: false` so that you never ever repeat this mistake again.

Comment: Why do you need `async: false`?

Comment: so what should I do. How I can achieve my requirements

Comment: You should pass a callback function to your helper method. Welcome to the AJAX world. This world is asynchronous and the sooner you start thinking in terms of callbacks rather then passing return variables from your functions, the better for you :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov please could you show me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `async: true`. You should refactor your code so that your functions do not return values but rather take callbacks.

Example of what you should **not** be doing:

```
var internal_tags = null;

function getValue() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType:'json',
        contentType:'application/json',
        url: '/ajax-search-suggestions',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            internal_tags = data;
        }
    });
}
```

And here's the correct approach:

```
function getValue(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType:'json',
        contentType:'application/json',
        url: '/ajax-search-suggestions',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

so instead of:

```
var internal_tags = null;
getValue();
alert(internal_tags);
```

you should do this:

```
getValue(function(internal_tags) {
    alert(internal_tags);
});
```

I also recommend you looking at [jQuery's deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: thanks for your comment. Problem is, I want to use `internal_tags` from ajax as parameter of other functions. For example: I am using `typeahead` jquery library where I want to use the `internal_tags` as parameter. i.e. 

`source: substringMatcher(internal_tags),`

Comment: So you will initialize the typeahead plugin **inside** the callback and not outside like you are doing it right now. It is only inside this callback that you have the result of the asynchronous call.